# Define new columns using other columns names

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let’s say I have a table A with a, b, c, d columns and a query:

```
SELECT 
  A.a + A.b AS sum,
  A.c - A.d AS difference 
FROM A
```

Is there a way I could define a new column like `sum * difference AS product` inside the query? (Using the names I defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can experiment with **with** clause

```
with precalculations as (
   SELECT 
     A.a + A.b AS sum,
     A.c - A.d AS difference 
   FROM A
) 
select pr.sum, pr.difference, pr.sum * pr.difference as product from precalculations pr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through one of the following ways:

1. Creating the variables as CTE
2. Converting your query into sub-query then querying it
3. Recalculating same calculation for each usage

If the equation is not that complex I would recommend to go with 3rd option.

Answer (score 0):

The "typical" methods for solving this use CTEs or subqueries.  However, you can also define the expressions in the `FROM` clause using a lateral join:

```
SELECT v.the_sum, v.the_difference,
       v.the_sum * v.the_difference as the_product
FROM A CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (A.a + A.b, A.c - A.d)
     ) v(the_sum, the_difference)
```